# long latency detected in simple Linux helloworld program

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a very simple hello world program that prints hello world, and then uses a pair of gettimeofday() to bracket around a usleep(50) call. I will then printf if the elapsed time between the two gettimeofday() calls is greater than 5ms.

When running on a Linux Vmware VM, and even on a native Linux laptop, I noticed that sometimes I would get elapsed time from 5ms to 10ms. I see much less printf on the native Linux laptop compared to the VMware, but it still does show up. On the native Linux laptop, the elapsed time is even up to 20ms, but I see much less printf than on the VMWare.

Why is this happening? Neither the VMware or the native Linux laptop is very busy at all.

How to mitigate this?

Thanks any insight.

Comment: Are you using x86?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to write software with a deterministic execution time, I would suggest the following (in some rough order of guesstimated impact):

1. Make sure you have a test environment where you're running Linux on-the-metal. I.e. no VM setups as Linux will always be at the mercy of the host OS's scheduler.
2. Be aware of the fact that any printing will mean doing some kind of I/O. Depending on the driver, the I/O might block on in-kernel threads or other processes (e.g. due to lock contention) before completing, thus the time of a call to something like `puts("Hello, World!")` will vary heavily.
3. Read up on the different scheduling policies offered by Linux; the manpage for `sched_setscheduler` is a good starting point. Note: `nice` is **NOT** the droid you're looking for.
4. If your system uses swap, get rid of latencies caused by page-faults by locking your application's memory in RAM; see the manpage for `mlock` and friends.
5. Swap out your kernel for one that is configured with `CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT` and related settings like threaded IRQs, priority inversion safe mutexes etc.
6. Read everything on [Real-Time Linux Wiki](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org), and then read it again.